# How to export multiple data frames to same xlsx file with R?

Tags: r, xlsx

Can somebody help me on how to export multiple data frames to the same xlsx-file in R?

I know how to do it excel, but getting an out of memory error after exporting few files. So I do not want to touch excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
write.table(df1, "test.csv", row.names = F)
write.table(df2, "test.csv", append = T, col.names = F, row.names = F)
```

EDIT:

To write to two different sheets in an xlsx-file:

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 2")
writeData(wb, 1, df1)
writeData(wb, 2, df2)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick help.This will replace the df1 by df2. What I want is to have df1 and df2 in separate sheets in test.csv file.

Comment: No...this will put the second data after the first data. There are no "sheets" in csv-files. The concept of "sheets" only exists in excel files.

Comment: a csv by design can only have one sheet. You could look at the (openxlsx)[https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx] package to write directly to a .xlsx file and write to different sheets if that is what you want

Comment: @guscht Thank You..!

Comment: @tbradley thank you..! That is what I want. I just read that this package does not depend on Java in the backend.. it would be helpful..

Comment: Edited my answer to use openxlsx and write to two different sheets.

Comment: Hi @guscht, thank you so much..! It's working with our Java dependency. I just have to install Rtools... Thanks for your simple codes, it saved me many days..

Comment: Hi @avinashtalari, great that it works for you. Could you mark my answer then as solving your problem?