# How to save file as XLSX in loop in R

Tags: r, excel, loops

I do need to save each loop result in EXCEL file my code is below :

```
library(xlsx)
library(bootstrap)
rawData <- read.xlsx("C:\\Users\\Taqwa\\Downloads\\9660.xlsx",1)
#load<-function(AveLd,AveOff,AveOn,DWELL_SEC)
#  + + sum((AveLd-AveOff)+AveOn)
#bootstrap(rawData,10000,load())
three_d_array <- array(0,dim = c(270, 6, 20))
for (i in 1:20){
  candy = 1:nrow(rawData)
  B=sample(candy,nrow(rawData) , replace=T)
  a=rawData[B,]
  three_d_array[,,i]=as.matrix(a)
}
```

Appreciated your help

Comment: Could you clarify whether you want the results to all be stored in a single .xlsx file (presumably one sheet per loop iteration?) or each one in a separate .xlsx file?

Comment: @MilanValášek yes that what i do need

Comment: Which one though?

Comment: i do need to write them all in the sam excel file @MilanValášek

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export multiple data frames to same xlsx file with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569798/how-to-export-multiple-data-frames-to-same-xlsx-file-with-r)

Answer (score 0):

before your loop, put:

```
out <- createWorkbook()
```

inside the loop:

```
assign(paste0("sheet", i), createSheet(wb = out, sheetName = as.character(i)))
# you don't really need your three_d_array
addDataFrame(x = a, sheet = eval(as.name(paste0("sheet", i))))
```

after the loop:

```
saveWorkbook(out, "[your path]/[file name].xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank You, but i kept getting this error , couldnot find function saveworkbook

Comment: Are you perhaps spelling it with a lower case w? It's `saveWorkbook`.